# Questions Starting With "I'm A Beginner"

Tags: discussion

I have met multiple new posts that start with "I'm a beginner" or "I just started this language" or something along those lines. I get that the OP wants to say that the mistakes in the code might be really easy to find and fix but I don't think that should be an excuse at all. Why are so many questions starting with something like "I'm just a beginner..."? I think that they should more research before asking if they think the mistake is easy to solve.

Comment: The only helpful information provided by such statements is upfront declaration of OP's technical level.  Knowing it makes it easier to tailor the level of detail in one's answer.

Comment: @PythonMaster I wouldn't be so quick to accept an answer on a discussion question on meta, if i were you. It means less people will contribute.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Starting posts with "I'm a beginner", or "this is the first time I've used Java WebFramework Foo-1000" etc is basically the same as ending posts with:
"Thanks" or "Your assistance is appreciated" etc.

It is noise.
It should be edited out.

we don't care if you are a beginner to the whole thing or an expert who is stuck on this one particular point.

---

<sub>To go a bit philosophical,
speaking to the generic second person know as You, not PythonMaster, but rather all those who ask.</sub>

<sub>Our answers are not answers to **Your problem** answers are answers to **The problem** and **you** are just the messenger who first brought **the problem** to the site. Where **The problem** with be answered, not just for **you** but for **all those who come after**</sub>

Comment: This might be minor contentious, there is the other view point that if a user described them self as a beginner, then you used different language than otherwise. I have another post on one of the site metas somewhere about it.

Comment: Well, a better thing to rely on than the posters self-proclaimed level (which is nearly always freshly-hatched or guru-haxor, if provided) is their demonstrated level of experience. Which in the case of self-declared levels is either obviously completely different, the level given (mythic rare if above beginner), or leach aka help-vampire. Observe that in neither case does the self-rating help.